# python, stub randomness twice in the same function

Tags: python, unit-testing

How would I stub the output of `pickCard()` function which is being called twice in `deal()` function? I want to test both losing and winning cases.
For example, I would like to have for the winning case, the first time `pickCard()` is called is given value `8` to `card1`, and second given value `10` to `card2`.

I have tried using @Mock.patch, but this works only for doing one call.

I have used  `self.blackjack.pickCard = MagicMock(return_value=8)` but again if i use it twice it will overwrite the return value

Here is the code:

```
import random

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

    def deal(self):
        card1 = self.pickCard()
        self.removeCards(card1)
        card2 = self.pickCard()
        return card1  + card2  > 16

    def pickCard(self):
        return random.choice(self.cards)

    def removeCards(self,card1):
        return self.cards.remove(card1)
```

The test file is:

```
import unittest
from mock import MagicMock
import mock
from lib.game import Game

class TestGame(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.game = Game()

    def test_0(self):#passing
        """Only cards from 1 to 10 exist"""
        self.assertListEqual(self.game.cards, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

    #Here is where I am finding difficulty writing the test
    def test_1(self):
        """Player dealt winning card"""
        with mock.patch('lib.game.Game.pickCard') as mock_pick:
            mock_pick.side_effect = (8, 10)
            g = Game()
            g.pickCard()
            g.pickCard()
            self.assertTrue(self.game.deal())
```

EDIT

I ran this test with above code, and I get this stack trace instead of passing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 tests/game_test.py line 26 in test_1
   self.assertTrue(self.game.deal())
 lib/game.py line 8 in deal
   card1 = self.pickCard()
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py line 1062 in __call__
   return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py line 1121 in _mock_call
   result = next(effect)
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py line 109 in next
   return _next(obj)
```

Do I need to put the two `g.pickCard()` elsewhere in the test? Or do I need to need to access this in the `self.game.deal()` method somehow?

Answer (score 3):

`mock.patch` is the way to go, but instead of `return_value` you should specify `side_effect=(8, 10)`

```
with mock.patch('lib.game.Game.pickCard') as mock_pick:
    mock_pick.side_effect = (8, 10)
    g = Game()
    print(g.pickCard())
    print(g.pickCard())

# 8
# 10
```

**EDIT #1**

Pick card was just for demonstration that different cards are picked.
In your code you pick both cards and then call `game.deal` which picks another two cards which are not mocked which raises `StopIteration`. Also, since your game object already exists (created in setUp) you should patch this object directly, not create a new game object, hence your `test_1` should be:

```
def test_1(self):
    """Player dealt winning card"""
    with mock.patch.object(self.game, 'pickCard') as mock_pick:
        mock_pick.side_effect = (8, 10)
        self.assertTrue(self.game.deal())
```

You path object's property `pickCard` with MagicMock and set it's side effects to 8 and 10 respectively.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect

Comment: If you need something way more sophisticated, which controls the behavior of `mock_pick` at each call, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783678/python-mock-builtin-open-in-a-class-using-two-different-files/38618056#38618056

Comment: Thanks for that @warownia1, I did see side effect elsewhere, but was not too sure how to use it. I am still getting issues with using the stubbed methods, see above in OP.

Comment: Edited to suit your particular case. My first answer was a generic example how to patch functions when multiple calls are required.